# scp files to the unix server and delete files on remote directory

Tags: shell

i want to copy a backup file from one unix server to another. Also it should check for the files older than 5 days and remove them from the remote server .

Answer (score 2):

This would do it.

> ssh user@host 'find /path/to/old_backups/* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;'

`-mtime +5` matches files created 5 days ago from midnight of the present day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but the above command wil remove the old files from remote , i also want to copy a file to the same location.

Comment: You can use RSYNC, SCP or SFTP to copy your files. An rsync example is `rsync -avz source_file user@hostname:/destination_path`

Comment: Also if i use rsync,scp or ssh , all these commands would prompt me for password . Is there a way i cn use them without entering a password everytime the script runs

Comment: There are two option. one is to use ssh key. the second option is to use expect.  `expect -c 'spawn rsync -avz source_file  $my_ruser\@$my_rhost -p $my_rport; expect \"*?password:*\" { send \"$my_rpass\r\"}; sleep 1; interact;'`

Comment: executing above code gives me an error , showing the usage of expect .

Comment: Here is the MAN page of expect. Please go through this. [link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)